# $p$ is prime, $a, b, c$ are integers, $a^2-b, b^2-c, c^2-a$ are divisible by p, but $a$ isn't. Proof, that $a^7-1$ is divisible by p.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I don't know where to begin. I know, that $a(a-1)+b(b-1)+c(c-1)$ is divisible by $p$, but what to do after?

Comment: Please make the body of your post a selfcontained text that make sense without knowing the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice - since $p$ does not divide $a$, by definition $a$ is invertible mod $p$.
$p$ divides all equation you wrote, therefore $a\equiv c^2\equiv b^4\equiv a^8\mod {p}$.
Therefore, $a^8\equiv a\mod{p}$. Multiplying both sides by $a^{-1}$, we get the desired result that $a^7-1\equiv 0\mod{p}$